# DyanamoDB - Global Secondary Index using GetItemRequest using Hash and Range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use the Java AWS sdk to get a document based on a Global Secondary Index.

Setup as follows:

**Hash Key:** MyId - Number

**Range Key:** MyDate - String

Here is my code to:

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> key = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
            key.put("MyId", new AttributeValue().withN("1234"));

            key.put("MyDate", new AttributeValue().withS("2014-10-12"));

        GetItemRequest go = new GetItemRequest().withTableName(tableName).withKey(key);
        GetItemResult result = getDynamoDBClient().getItem(gi);
```

But this always returns :

> The provided key element does not match the schema (Service:
>   AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400

What am I dong wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes, first you talk about GSI but you are doing [GetItemRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/GetItemRequest.html) by primary key. So perhaps you're missing something in your question.

Did you write in your question the primary key of the table or the GSI definition?

You can only `Query` by GSI, `Get` is still based on primary key.

Comment: Yes so my i am trying a get on a GSI. Thats the problem. I though you could. Changing to query. thanks.